# How to take single snapshots from a webcam?

Tags: java, windows, webcam, capture

I want to take a snapshot with my webcam using java and save it to a jpg file. What are the steps needed to do so? A tutorial would be greatly appreciated.

Greetings,
Burkhard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the JMF (Java Media Framework) is a good starting point. However, I did not succeed with it.

I finally found the solution [here](http://www.comp.rgu.ac.uk/staff/fh/CM4062/mis/jmf/FrameGrab.html).

The important part being:

```
Buffer buf = frameGrabber.grabFrame();
// Convert frame to an buffered image so it can be processed and saved
Image img = (new BufferToImage((VideoFormat) buf.getFormat()).createImage(buf));
buffImg = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(this), img.getHeight(this), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
//TODO saving the buffImg
```

Comment: An answer that I just posted here will be useful for anyone else who wants to do a similar thing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22107132/398316

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for might be the Java Media Framework (JMF).
See the [Sun Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/solutions/index.html). I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using JMyron instead of JMF. JMyron is easy to use for accessing webcam. To save the captured image you just need to save the BufferedImage using ImageIO.write(); this blog post [How To Use Webcam Using Java](http://howto-java.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-use-webcam-using-java.html)is usefull to start using JMyron.

Answer (score 1):

Try [webcam-capture](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture) project.

This code will take a snapshot from webcam (embedded, connected to USB or IP camera) and save it into JPG file:

```
Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
webcam.open()
BufferedImage image = webcam.getImage();
ImageIO.write(image, "JPG", new File("test.jpg"));
```