# When I try to capture a image from my webcam, its take a all black image

Tags: java

I've downloaded a [java project](http://webcamapplet.sourceforge.net/) in which interacts with my webcam. I'm trying to add the functionality to take pictures through the webcam, or just capture the current image and save it in my C: directory

I created a button called Capture (startC) and did an ActionListener

**ActionListener**

```
startC.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {           
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {               
                  // Grab a frame                 
                 FrameGrabbingControl fgc = new FrameGrabbingControl() {

                        @Override
                        public Component getControlComponent() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            return null;
                        }                       

                        @Override
                        public Buffer grabFrame() {
                            // return null;
                            return new Buffer();
                        }
                    };  
                  player.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl");    
                  buf = fgc.grabFrame();                  

                  // Convert it to an image               
                  BufferToImage btoi = new BufferToImage((VideoFormat)buf.getFormat());
                  // btoi = new BufferToImage((VideoFormat)buf.getFormat());    
                  img = btoi.createImage(buf);       

                  // show the image 
                  //imgpanel.setImage(img);       

                  // save image 
                  try {
                    saveJPG(img,"c:\\test.jpg");                    
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }
        });
```

**UPDATED ActionListener**

```
startC.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Vector devices = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(null);
                CaptureDeviceInfo cdi = null;
                for (Iterator i = devices.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                    cdi = (CaptureDeviceInfo) i.next();
                    /*
                     * Get the first Video For Windows (VFW) capture device. Use
                     * the JMF registry tool in the bin directory of the JMF
                     * distribution to detect available capture devices on your
                     * computer.
                     */
                    if (cdi.getName().startsWith("vfw:"))
                        break;
                }

                try {
                    player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(cdi.getLocator());
                    player.start();
                } catch (NoPlayerException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                } catch (CannotRealizeException e3) {
                    e3.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e4) {
                    e4.printStackTrace();
                }

                // start the Timer with 3s intervals
                new Timer(3000, this).start();

                // Grab a frame from the capture device
                FrameGrabbingControl fgc = (FrameGrabbingControl) player.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl");
                buf = fgc.grabFrame();
                BufferToImage btoi = new BufferToImage((VideoFormat) buf
                        .getFormat());
                img = btoi.createImage(buf);
});
```

**SaveJPG method**

```
      public static void saveJPG(Image img, String s) throws IOException    
      {       
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(640, 480, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        File outputfile = new File("C:\\saved.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(bi, "png", outputfile);
}
```

The problem is that when I click Capture, is simply saving a screen all black, and that's not what the webcam is focusing.

Can someone help?

**@UPDATE**

Line 520 = `buf = fgc.grabFrame();`

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.colorfulwolf.webcamapplet.WebcamApplet$6.actionPerformed(WebcamApplet.java:520)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: [SSCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @Keyser, My question is clear.

Comment: Yes, but that's not what the link is about.

Comment: `public static void saveJPG(Image img, String s) throws IOException    
      {       
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(640, 480, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        File outputfile = new File("C:\\saved.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(bi, "png", outputfile);
}` -> you are not using img at all ... so you are saving a new **blank** instance of BufferedImage

Comment: @Fildor this is my `saveJPG` method. How would be my `saveJPG` method ?

Comment: Fildor's saveJPG implementation is correct; yours is not.  However, that's only a small issue; you don't appear to be capturing the image correctly.  `player.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl");` What is the purpose of this? I would assume it returns a `FrameGrabbingControl`, and if so, I would assume that it is the FrameGrabbingControl that `fgc` should be, for use with image capturing.

Comment: @Vulcan I saw this method to capture image from webcam, googling about it.

Comment: I don't believe you've copied it exactly, because earlier you had your FrameGrabbingControl implementation returning null for a buffer, and now it returns a new Buffer instead.  I think this is where the issue lies; the buffer doesn't have a valid configuration because it's not the one issued from the player.

Comment: @Vulcan, Just to answer your question `What is the purpose of this?`, I saw in http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/javax/media/control/FrameGrabbingControl.html that the line `player.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl")`, will get the FrameGrabbingControl, that according to the API, is the interface to grab a still video frame from the video stream. This control can be exported by a Renderer or a Player via the getControl method.

Comment: @Vulcan If I create an instance of `FrameGrabbingControl`, will appears a override anottation in `grabFrame` method, that actually returns null, but I change to return a new Buffer()

Comment: I agree that that is the purpose of it, but I don't believe you are using it correctly, because you don't use the control returned by `player.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl")`.  Trying setting `fgc = // ^...`.

Comment: @Vulcan I tryied put this `FrameGrabbingControl fgc = (FrameGrabbingControl) player.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl");
    buf = fgc.grabFrame();` but I got error of `NullPointerException` in the `buf = fgc.grabFrame();`

Comment: Something very similar to this http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~bemaf/arquivos/prp/Capturing.txt

Comment: I found a good sample here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078689/how-to-take-single-snapshots-from-a-webcam

Comment: Seems like your `player` is returning `null` when you attempt to get a control from it.  Try out that other sample.

Comment: @Vulcan For me doesn't matter the way that I'll get this image, I saw something using JMF, Myron, JavaCV. For me, can be anyone.

Comment: Debugging my application, I discover something strange. In this two lines `player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(cdi.getLocator());` and `player.start();` The `cdi.getLocator()` get `javasound://44100`. Why JavaSound?

Comment: I updated my question with my `ActionListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching and googling it, I found a solution to my problem.

**SOLUTION**

```
startC.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                OpenCVWebCam webCam = (OpenCVWebCam) cam;
                try {
                    webCam.start();
                } catch (Exception e3) {                    
                    e3.printStackTrace();
                }

                OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
                try {
                    grabber.start();
                } catch (Exception e3) {            
                    e3.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    IplImage frame = grabber.grab();
                    BufferedImage out = frame.getBufferedImage();   
                    File outputfile = new File("c:\\saved.png");
                    ImageIO.write(out, "png", outputfile);
                } catch (Exception e2) {                    
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
}
});
```

The goal has been reached, and the image was saved. After that, with the image saved in my server, occurs a message in my Console tab.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x776a224d, pid=5864, tid=5576
#
# JRE version: 7.0_05-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.1-b03 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x3224d]  EtwEventEnabled+0x1ca
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\lucas\workspace\WebcamApplet\bin\hs_err_pid5864.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while but try:

```
public static void saveJPG(Image img, String s) throws IOException { 
    File outputfile = new File("C:\\saved.jpg"); 
    ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", outputfile); 
}
```

Comment: The Image instance you gave into the saveJPG was `null`. So check your  Image-retrieval.